# Install Zip on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

I am interested in setting my [I9300](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9300) to a Ubuntu Touch phone and give it a try. But I am having serious problem on this.

The wiki says to flash the **Ubuntu-Touch-i9300_build3.zip** first and then the **raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip**. And here is the problem: I can successfully flash the first zip, but there's only **wily-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.tar.gz** on Ubuntu's touch images. Then I need to transform the `.tar.gz` into `.zip`. (the version may not be a big problem.)

When I try to use `tar zxvf file.tar.gz` to untar the file, and then use GUI to compress it into `.zip`, it tells me that `Permission denied`.

So, how can I get the **wily-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip**? Thanks.

***EDIT:***
I have some new ideas, and I try to extract it into file.tar, and compress it. It turns out that it becomes file.zip and contains a file.tar. Is this still recognizable to the phone if it only accept zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may take a look in http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/
This is what I have found while I was trying to port Ubuntu Touch to my device.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I took a look. But they are just `tar.gz`files in the repo. How can you port it to your devices?

Comment: I'm making an assumption that you have used [this instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9300). If you have built it with target bacon (mka bacon) it should have built .zip file ready to be installed on the device. However I do not know if it would incorporate platform independent stuff. In [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/#anchor5) porting instructions, right before "cleaning", is explained how to incorporate touch tar.gz files and the system.img into one file. Flashing is explained in different section of the same article.

Comment: Thanks. You mean I should build the package myself?

Comment: I think that if you have `system.img`, `boot.img` and `recovery.img` you can use them  together with the files from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/ and the `rootstock-touch-install` tool to create installation package and install it to the device. I haven't try it though -- I am stuck with my boot.img being to large for my devices partitioning scheme.

Comment: That sounds good. but how can I use the command `rootstock-touch-install` ?

Comment: The tool needs to be downloaded using `bzr`. In [this link](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/#anchor5) there is instruction how to do so (look for `bzr` in monospaced text). If you do not have `bzr` installed i think it should be available from Ubuntu's software repositories.

Comment: You mean that I can use that code from your link to generate a zip package for my device?

Comment: Also, is the some 15GB resources mentioned in the link also required? If yes, then there is more trouble.

Comment: The source code (those 15 GB) in your case is not necessary, only the tool downloaded with `bzr` and the latest package from cdimage.

Comment: By saying *the tool downloaded with `bzr`* you mean that long command it gives to download the packages? If yes, but `apt-get` can't find the package `mingw32`.

Comment: `mingw32` is port of gcc for *windows*. It is possible to get mingw libraries for linux to cross compile programs for windows on linux machine, however I do not think it is what you require. By _the tool downloaded with `bzr`_ I mean `rootstock-touch-install`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35221/discussion-between-chromium-and-krzysztof-pilch).